# Terminal open (possibly hidden) file using TextEdit

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, osx, sudo

I have been trying to run the following command:

`sudo open -a textEdit  ~/.bashrc`. I get an error stating that the file does not exist. But then `sudo nano ~/.bashrc` opens up fine. I am not familiar with the nano interface nor command line so I wish to open the file in textEdit.

Is the file truely not there or is it a hidden file?

Comment: i just tried your command:  open -a textEdit  ~/.bashrc and it worked fine on my machine. Are you in your home directory when you issue the command?

Comment: you can unhide all files by typing CMD + SHIFT + .

Comment: Why do you want to edit `.bashrc` with `sudo` ?

Answer (score 1):

You should first unhide all files by typing <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + .  Then try opening the file with textEdit,